# Background Images in HTML Email

Tags: html

I just want to add background image and want to write text over it. I have tried everything. Please give me full proof method for this.
Thank You

Comment: "*I have tried everything."* Tell people **what** you've tried, ideally with examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with Z-index: just google it about Z-index: You can get online example in W3schools

See here: **http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_zindex**

Answer (score 1):

Since it's an e-mail its better to use oldschool HTML when possible, since some e-mail readers dont support CSS properly.

To achive a background under text you can use:

```
<table background="http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/deepsea.gif">
```

See in live action here: http://jsfiddle.net/Tub3x/

Comment: Alredy tried it..bt still not working in Outlook. Bt, Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1307242 do you remember to ALLOW images in outlook? It will automaticly remove all images for security reasons. See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/843018 ... Since this way is oldschool HTML outlook should have no problems, if allowed to download images :)

Answer (score 1):

use  and apply background image to it and 
Add new input type text for write your text.

like this

```
<div style="background-image:url('imageurl') ">
  <your text box here>
</div>
```

have a nice day..

Comment: Thanks..but unfortunately, background-image is not supported by Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

While giving an image on the email, the link should **always** be relative path.

Here is example email content to show what i mean

```
$content = '<div style="background:url(\'http://yourdomain.com/images/yourimage.jpg\');">';
                                      //  ^ See the direct path to the image given here
$content .= "your text";
$content .= "</div>";
```

Comment: Yeah, m using the relative path only.. I want to write text over an image. Do u kno how to do it??

Comment: @user1307242, If you use above code, `your text` will appear right over the background div.

Answer (score 0):

@user1307242 try this

```
<div> 
  <div style="position:absolute; z-index:-1">
    <img url='image path'/>
  </div>
  <div style="z-index:2">
    <Text box>
  </div>
</div>
```